# Failing to calculate the percentage of key strokes being numbers

Tags: c

The code below is supposed to count the number of keys pressed and print it on the screen along with the percentage of number keys pressed. When I run the code the percentage is always 0. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
int c,count=0,count1=0;
float d;
while ((c=getch()))
{
  count = count++;
 if (c=='1'||c=='2'||c=='3'||c=='4'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='7'||c=='8'||c=='9'||c=='0')
  {
      count1=count1++;
  }
  if (c=='!')
  {
      d=(count1/count*100);
      printf("\nnumbers of keys is %d percentage of number keys is %.3d percent",count,d);
  }

  }
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Questioning. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Incrementing, you're doing that wrong too.

Comment: +1 to both the comments above and 1 below. 1) Do not use all caps, 2) Do not use undefined behavior (`x=x++` == undefined behavior, look up sequence points). 3) Integer division is fail.

Comment: Division. You are doing it wrong also.

Comment: printf formatting (%.3).  You're also doing this wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
count = count++;
```

and

```
count1 = count1++;
```

are undefined behaviour, so all bets are off. Even if it weren't undefined behaviour, it would not do what you want because `x++` returns the value of `x` before the increment.

Let that be simply `++count;` and `++count1;`.

Comment: Good catch. `count++;` and `count1++;` would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though `d` is a float, `count` and `count1` are `int`. You're therefore doing integer math when you say

```
d=(count1/count*100);
```

Do this instead:

```
d=((float)count1/count*100);
```

Casting `count1` to `float` [converts the division to floating point](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4bb.html).